# Google Maps API - infobox.js and markerwithlabel.js - google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my google maps webapp, I continue to get this error:

```
infobox.js:126 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

It is first triggered by this, inside infobox.js:

```
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

I have read several stack articles on this exact topic, including:

- [Async Google Maps API v3 undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184956/async-google-maps-api-v3-undefined-is-not-a-function/14185834#14185834)
- [Google Maps API: markerwithlabel.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692791/google-maps-api-markerwithlabel-js-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-def)
- [Google Maps API throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" only when using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe)

Here is my `<head>` section:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paypal/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyD1vT***********1s6tNOgL2F44P8&callback=initialize&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TreasureHunt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/infobox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

Inside TreasureHunt.js is my initialize() function:

```
function initialize() {
    // set up basic/default world map, zoomed out, showing globe
    var mapOptions = {
  ...
    }
}
```

I have tried moving the js references to different locations but nothing works. I am forced by google to use the `&callback=initialize` approach, else my map doesn't load at all. I used to be able to use `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` instead of the async, but that no longer works, the map simply doesn't load. I have tried putting TreasureHunt.js both before and after the maps API js file but nothing works. Always inside infobox and markerwithlabel it thinks the google object doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong?

(Note: 1 year ago this all worked perfectly until one day when my local maps js script stopped working and google now requires referencing the js from their server - so I fixed it, and then these other problems occurred.)

Comment: remove async and defer from the google maps script

Comment: And remove callback=initialize.  If you load the API asynchronously, everything that depends on it must be in the callback function, or certain to run after the callback.

Comment: As stated in the original post, when I remove callback=initialize, the map doesn't load. That's the whole reason I had to do it. And Google Maps docs say to do it that way. Also, why the downvote for no reason and no explanation?

Comment: You  didn't include a [mcve] in your question so we could tell that `initialize` wasn't being called somewhere else in your code/page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. change the script include from:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyD1vT***********1s6tNOgL2F44P8&callback=initialize&libraries=places"></script>
```

to (remove `async defer` and `&callback=initialize`):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyD1vT***********1s6tNOgL2F44P8&libraries=places"></script>
```

2. Add (code to call the initialize function after the DOM has rendered):

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);